# How can I pastebin 2 commands?

Tags: command-line, pastebin

When I try to pastebin 2 command like this:

```
echo Merry && echo Christmas | pastebinit
```

It only pastebins the second command, and gives the first as output:

```
Merry
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9605648/
```

Now I could just do:

```
echo Merry Christmas | pastebinit
```

And that would work, but I want to run 2 separate commands, and pipe the output to `pastebinit`, I can't:

```
sudo apt-get install christmas && sudo apt-get update | pastebinit
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install christmas && sudo apt-get update | tee output.txt && pastebinit -f output.txt` work?

Comment: No, `tee` only picks up the output of the second command.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. Muru's solution seems to work though!

Comment: Yes, and I believe your command just made my computer hang :p could have been coincidence, but the command never ended, I forgot to stop it and then I had to force restart...

Comment: That... makes no sense.

Comment: Probably coincidence tho... I'll check in a VB later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it to make a compound command:

```
{ echo Merry && echo Christmas;} | pastebinit
```

In general, to pipe the output of multiple commands in sequence to another command, do:

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; ...;} | cmd
```

or

```
(cmd1; ... ) | cmd
```

Comment: @Tim As I understand it, for the case of pipes, no. Braces are usually used to run commands in the current shell and parentheses for running in a subshell, but pipes force the usage of a subshell anyway. But I could be wrong. It looks like a good question for [unix.se].

Comment: Okay - I believe that edit is needed btw.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you couldn't first redirect the output of the two commands into a file (using append for the output of the second command), and then pipe that to pastebinit?

```
echo Merry > out.txt && echo Christmas >> out.txt && cat out.txt | pastebinit
```

Maybe redirect stderr to the out file also.

Comment: If you're going to `cat` anyway, avoid manually creating a file: `cat <(echo Merry) <(echo Christmas) | pastebinit`

Comment: OP doesn't want the second command executed if the first one returns an error condition.  Unfortunately, your edit omits that requirement.  Perhaps this:  cat <(echo Merry && echo Christmas) | pastebinit

Answer (score 0):

Here follows a *work-around* to answer the question of "how do I grab complex output on the CLI?"

Should be useful:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ script xmas
Script started, file is xmas
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ echo Merry && echo Christmas
Merry
Christmas
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ exit
exit
Script done, file is xmas
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat xmas 
Script started on 2017-10-27 06:37:59-0700
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ echo Merry && echo Christmas
Merry
Christmas
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ exit
exit

Script done on 2017-10-27 06:38:23-0700
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ pastebinit xmas
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25830406/
thufir@dur:~$
```

Here's the pastebin [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25830406/) on ubuntu, as above.  Reference `man script` for how to use `typescript`.

Note that you can execute scripts, interact, etc.  The `script` command just logs everything into a file.  Not quite sure how to make it more [readable](https://askubuntu.com/q/969892/45156) without futzing with the console/shell configuration...

Basically, if you turn off all colors, etc, it looks better.